# Add and remove elements from a single table without affecting ng-repeat array

Tags: angularjs

I use ng-repeat to generate some tables, like this:

```
<table ng-repeat="table in tables">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
   <th>
     <a href='#' ng-click="removerow()">remove row</a>
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
    <a href='#' ng-click="addrow()">Add row</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to add and remove rows in a single table without affecting the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI reflects the model. If you're using the same `rows` object for all the tables, it will affect all the other tables. If you don't want the rows in the individual tables affecting the other tables, you need to use a different object for your `ng-repeat`. You can simply create a copy of `rows` for each table.

Comment: I'm new to angular and don't know how to do that, I imagine I need to run a for loop on the objects in tables, then crate new row arrays with angularjs.copy?

Comment: What does your javascript look like? How are `tables` and `rows` set into the `$scope`?

Comment: It creates arrays based on json files:   $http.get('tables.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.tables = data;
        });

Comment: So, does each `table` object have a `rows` property? If that's the case, they already are their own object. `ng-repeat="row in rows"` won't work though since there's no `rows` property in the `$scope`. You just need to reference it from the `table` property that gets put into the `$scope` from the 1st `ng-repeat`. Something like `ng-repeat="row in table.rows"`

Comment: No they don't, but now you got me thinking... Maybe I need to redesign the whole page. Thanks :)